# Save a portion of a binary file

Tags: c#, wpf, binary-data

I worked out how to read a large file into a smaller file, but only if I start at the beginning. I would like to be able to read from the middle to an arbitrary point. I realize it sounds crazy, but I have my reasons. I keep getting nothing written out to the file when I set the position greater than 0 for some reason. I will end up with a file full of null values.

I thought this would read 300K in from 2.5MB into the file.

```
    public static FileStream stream = new FileStream(@"file.dat", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    public static FileStream shortFile = null;
    int limit = 300000;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        byte[] block = new byte[limit];


        using (FileStream fs = File.Create("tempfile.dat"))
        {
            var newposition = stream.Seek(2500000, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            stream.Position = newposition;
            while (stream.Read(block, 0, limit) > 0 && stream.Position <= limit)
            {
               fs.Write(block, 0, block.Length);
            }
        }

        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

Comment: `"I worked out how to read a large file into a smaller file"`.  Did you mean write?

Comment: Yes, that is what I was meaning.

Comment: The problem is your `while` (and you don't have to set the `.Position` after calling `.Seek`), take a look at this part: `&& stream.Position <= limit`, since you move the position 2500000 bytes in, `stream.Position > limit` and the while loop doesn't execute.

Answer (score 1):

You have said *"I thought this would read 300K in from 2.5MB into the file"*; but you have the `limit` and the Seek values the other way around. The Seek position needs to be set to 300000; the `limit` should be 2500000.

Other tips:

1. Streams are disposable so better to keep them as local variables, declared in `using` blocks (i.e. do that for `stream`).
2. You don't need to set `stream.Position = newposition;` since that is what the Seek has just done.